# ITunes and in app purchase

Tags: in-app-purchase, itunes, app-store-connect, storekit

i m new in in app purchase and not getting how to purchase a song from itunes gallery using my app and stream or download the song with in my app?
Is it possible to purchase and download song from itune to my app ?

Please suggest me or help me what should i do ?

Comment: What is iTunes gallery?

Answer (score 0):

In-app purchasing & `StoreKit` are for allowing the purchase of items you create and have approved by Apple. It isn't for purchasing items from other vendors and it isn't for purchasing songs from iTunes. You can play a song from the user's iPod library using the Media Player framework. See Apple's AddMusic example project for that functionality.

Answer (score 0):

iOS6 introduced SKStoreProductViewController to allow developers to cross promote or sell other content from iTunes or the App Store without taking the user out of your app.

You can find the documentation here:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKITunesProductViewController_Ref/Introduction/Introduction.html

You can find more discussions on stackoverflow here:
https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=SKStoreProductViewController